# Add RoleAssignment to a Resource Group programmatically

Tags: active-directory, roles, azure-sdk

I'm implementing an application in Java that has access to Azure via a secure principal and that creates some Resource Groups.
I would like, given an AD Group Name specified via configuration, to add a specific Role Assignment for that AD Group to the Resource Groups.
Is it feasible via Azure Java SDK or I need to use REST APIs?
Which permissions the service principal needs to:

1. Read an AD group given its name
2. Assign a RolePermission to a newly created Resource Group for that AD Group

I need to ask to our ActiveDirectory team which permission must be enabled to my Service principal.

TIA
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if we can use java sdk to implement this requirement, but I know we can request rest api to do it. Please refer to the steps below:

**1.** We need to get the id of the role definition by request [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roledefinitions/list) api: `GET https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions?api-version=2015-07-01`

The URI parameter `{scope}` should be like `/subscriptions/{your subscription id}/resourceGroups/{your resource group name}`

For example, here I get the id of "**Contributor**" role.
[image]

**2.** Then request [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/create) api: `PUT https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/{roleAssignmentName}?api-version=2015-07-01`  to create role assignment(assign the role for resource group contributor to your ad group).

The {scope} should be `/subscriptions/{your subscription id}/resourceGroups/{your resource group name}` and you can specify a `{roleAssignmentName}` as you like(should be valid GUID).

The request body should be like below:

```
{
    properties: {
    "roleDefinitionId": "{the id of Contributor role which we get in step 1}",
    "principalId": "{the object id of your AD group}"
  }
}
```

**3.** Finish the two apis request above, we can find the AD group has been assigned with the role of "Contributor" for the resource group.
[image]

Comment: Hi Hury Shen, I was able to execute the firs REST GET API but the when I try to assign the the group with the Contributor role I got a 403 Forbidden result. Do you know which permission must be assigned to the application service principal to execute this API?

Comment: @FlavioBarisone If you want do the assign operation, you should at least be the owner of the resource group first. If still can do assign operation, maybe you need to be the owner of the subscription.

Comment: @FlavioBarisone May I know if your problem was solved ? If it the solution works, could you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~